# Using an extension method on session a variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, extension-methods, session-variables

I've created the following extension method:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function ToIntegerOrDefault(ByVal valueToParse As Object, Optional ByVal defaultValue As Integer = 0) As Integer
  Dim retVal As Integer = 0
  If Not Integer.TryParse(valueToParse.ToString, retVal) Then
    retVal = defaultValue
  End If
  Return retVal
End Function
```

and I'd like to use this extension method on session variables like so:

```
ReadOnly Property NodeID As Integer
  Get
    Return Session(SessionVariables.SELECTED_NODE_ID).ToIntegerOrDefault()
  End Get
End Property
```

However, upon invoking the method before the session variable has been set, a `NullReferenceException` is thrown with message `Object variable or With block variable not set.`

Is there a safe way to utilize an extension method on a session variable in this way (given that the session variable may be null)?

Comment: You code looks fine, is the key on your session valid?

Comment: I would check to see that the value is null first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use an extension method for an `object` type (it should be another type) [VB.NET: impossible to use Extension method on System.Object instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227888/vb-net-impossible-to-use-extension-method-on-system-object-instance).
A module with extension methods has to be imported so you can use:

```
ReadOnly Property NodeID As Integer
  Get
    Return ToIntegerOrDefaultSession(SessionVariables.SELECTED_NODE_ID))
  End Get
End Property
```

Alternatively you can rewrite the extension method

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function ToIntegerOrDefault(Sess As HttpSessionState, KeyOFvalueToParse As String, Optional ByVal defaultValue As Integer = 0) As Integer
  Dim retVal As Integer = 0
  If Not Integer.TryParse(Sess(KeyOFvalueToParse).ToString, retVal) Then
    retVal = defaultValue
  End If
  Return retVal
End Function
```

And call

```
Session.ToIntegerOrDefault(SessionVariables.SELECTED_NODE_ID)
```

Or define extension method for `String` and call

```
Cstr(Session(SessionVariables.SELECTED_NODE_ID)).ToIntegerOrDefault()
```

Comment: Excellent, thorough answer.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Give Session a default value when you declare it.  If it's a list using the new keyword will do the trick.  If it's something else you'll have to show what it is.

Comment: It would be nice if you provided an example of how to do it.

Comment: How do you provide an example on initializing a collection, when the OP doesn't say what the collection is?  Just off the top of my head I can come up with half a dozen different collections.

Comment: Hi there.  The extension method accepts an object, attempts to parse it as an integer, then returns the parsed value (or if it fails, returns the optional default).  There are no collections.