# C# extension method being used in a VB.Net project - Error: Public member '' to type 'String' not found

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a class with several method extensions made in a C# project. When I try to use it in a vb.net project I get an error ("**Public member 'ConvertToDBNull' to type 'String' not found**"). Is there anything different to do?
Below is a simple example that generates the same problem:

**C# project:**

```
public static class Extensions
{

    public static object ConvertToDBNull(this object value)
    {
        return DBNull.Value;
    }

}
```

**VB.Net project:**

```
Dim test As Object = "test"
Dim convert As Object = test.ConvertToDBNull()
```

Comment: You have an Imports for the namespace Extensions is in?

Comment: @Ralf, Yes. If I do this ***test.ToString().ConvertToDBNull()*** he manages to get to the method, but it doesn't make sense to have to convert to String first.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227888/vb-net-impossible-to-use-extension-method-on-system-object-instance) is some discussion about the problem. Looks like it has nothing todo that the Extension has been written in C# but a pure VB design thingy(late binding). It would also happen if the extension was written in VB.

Comment: "it doesn't make sense to have to convert to String first" - It is not doing a conversion.  You are receiving the **runtime error** because you have late-binding enabled in the VB project (`Option Strict Off`).  With `Option Strict On`, the project would not have compiled.  As others have stated, VB does not allow Extension methods on the Object type.  This does not prevent you calling the method directly (`Dim convert As Object = ConvertToDBNull(test)`).